# How do I get the form submitted data in a custom module?

Tags: 7, forms

I have create a webform in Drupal 7. I want to access the submitted data in a custom module.

I used `my_module_form_submit($form, &$form_state)` but no data has been found.
Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get submitted data based on sid, I think below code will be helpful for you

```
 function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  if ($form_id == 'WEBFORM_'){ 
module_load_include('inc','webform','includes/webform.submissions');
$sid = 10;
$submission = webform_get_submissions(array('sid' => $sid));
$nid = $submission[$sid]->nid;

$web_submission = webform_get_submission($nid, $sid);
$node = node_load($nid);
$output = webform_submission_render($node, $web_submission, NULL, 'html');

print $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x) and change the submit function. Below is the code"

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  if ($form_id == 'WEBFORM_'){ // give your webform id here.
    if (isset($form['actions']['submit'])) {
     $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] ='webform_custom_submit';
    }
  }
}

function webform_custom_submit(&$form, &$form_state){
  $values = $form_state['values']; // Here you can get all $form_state values
}
```

Comment: If I already had submitted the form then what can i do ?